# What is the difference between the Start date (read Start time) and Schedule execution times for Scheduled trigger in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to trigger my pipeline daily at 12:00 AM UTC. So, I am setting up a Schedules trigger.
I am confused about value of "Execute at these times/Schedule execution times". I mean what is the diff b/w the Start time I specified which is 12:00:00 AM and execution time?

Do I also need to specify execution time 12:00 or I can leave it empty and only Start date will work to run pipeline daily at 12:00 AM UTC?

[image: Please check image here]

Answer (score 0):

The start time value that is specified in `start date` field is the time when the trigger starts running. While the "Execute at these times" field specifies the specific times of day when the trigger should execute.

> Do I also need to specify execution time 12:00 or I can leave it empty and only Start date will work to run pipeline daily at 12:00 AM UTC?

- Both time in start date and execution time are different and used for different purpose.
- If you want to trigger pipeline every day at 12:00 hours, you should mention the value in `execution at these times` fields.
- The start date value `9/8/2023 12:00 AM` ensures that the trigger will be effective from that datetime.

**Reference**: MS document on [Create schedule triggers - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory)